# Built .so file by cocos2dx keep showing UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x android project with a .so file. 
When run with android platform version 8, it crashes with Error like below.

```
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2582)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library game not found
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   at com.nwm.klp.client.sample.sample.<clinit>(sample.java:37)
10-16 19:03:50.958: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):   ... 15 more
```

I built the libgame.so in right place and loaded with right name. I'm sure because it works perfectly well in another platform version device (jelly bean) and, as far as I know, cocos2d-x supports 8 version.

Can you give some advice about this?

Thank you.

Comment: wrong ABI version fx: lib is x86 and device ARM ...

Comment: Thanx for your comment :) but.. my test device galaxy 1 is armeabi-v7 according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/BSibq5sp5Lo , 
and I wrote it in application.mk file, APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a ..

so device and lib file is arm, both.

Comment: The README file for cocos2d-x v2.2 says: "If you use gles20 branch or cocos2d-x v2.0 above, only android 2.3 and higher are supported" so you may be out of luck.

Comment: oh.. and if you can give me more help, I wonder where you get it that information. I've surf cocos2d-x web page, but at a glance, I can't find that. Thanx.